# With REQUEST_URI i get id node or alias path?

Tags: 7, uri

I have a big doubt. In `template.php` I am using:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

what will the output like:  `node/id-number`**or** `/Alias_page` ?

Comment: You don't have to be sorry for asking a question, that's what this site is about. As for the real part, I just tested, and the returned value from that variable is the `path_alias`. What are you up to ? Drupal has many helpful functions for that kind of stuff.

Comment: @mchar in template.php i have an "if" and if condition is true (request_uri == page x) add js file. But i want to know what return.. Because this work also if i write == "/node/id-number" and also if i write == "/page-alias". How is possible?

Comment: I don't know what [type](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) of variables you are comparing there,so I can't tell. In other words, make sure that both variables are of the same type!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to check on which page are you, is to use the [`current_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7) function. Below is an example:

```
if (current_path() == 'your/system/path') {
  // Do whatever.
}
```

This is the best way because aliases can change, while system paths stay the same.

However, if you really need the aliased path, use the [`drupal_get_path_alias()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7) function instead.

Comment: But current path what returned? "Http://www.example.com/node/id-number" ??? And i can use it in template.php ??? Please can you show me an example? Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I didn't quite understand your comment.

Comment: if is a particular page add js file a this page. But i don't know what return current_path(). Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @user3162975 It's confusing why you'd need one - what happened when you tried it? Did you see "node/[id]" or did you see the alias of that node? That's your answer

Comment: alias, i came back at home and i read api drupal for "current_path" so with it i can know node/id not alias :) sorry me but for me is too difficult read and write english (i'm italian) and italian drupal community is tooooo little :/ however i think that will use 'http://www.example.com'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: If you use `current_path()`, it will return `node/XXX`. If you use `drupal_get_path_alias()`, it will return `path-to-your-node`. That's pretty much it. Use the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module and the `dpm()` function to check what's available to you and what are the values you get.